# Does $R_1<R_2$ impliy $\frac{b_n}{a_n}\to 0$ for two power series?

Tags: power-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,\quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$$
be two power series with radius of convergence $R_1$ and $R_2$
satisfying
$$0<R_1<R_2<+\infty,\  a_n\neq0,n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Can we have the following result:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=0.$$

What I have try:
If $$\frac{1}{R_1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\ \mbox{and}\ 
\frac{1}{R_2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|n_n|},$$
it is easy to show the above result.
But,in general,
$$\frac{1}{R_1}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\ \mbox{and}\ 
\frac{1}{R_2}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|b_n|}.$$

Other method:
If we choose $r\in(R_1,R_2)$, then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nr^n$$
is convergent, and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nr^n$$
is divergent,
and
$$b_nr^n=\frac{b_n}{a_n}\cdot a_nr^n\to0.$$
If we know $|a_nr^n|\to \infty$,
then we will get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=0.$$

Any hlep and hints will welcome or counterexample can be provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample:

- $a_n = 1$ for odd $n$, $a_n = 1/3^n$ for even $n$.
- $b_n = 1/2^n$.

Then $R_1 = 1 < 2 = R_2$, and $b_{2n}/a_{2n} \to \infty$.

Similarly one can construct examples such that $b_n/a_n$ has arbitrary prescribed subsequential limits.

One can only conclude that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} b_n/a_n = 0$. In particular, if the limit exists, it must be zero.

Comment: Nice answer! Could you give some extra conditions making the result is right?

Comment: @Riemann: A simple condition would be that the limit exists: In that case it must be zero.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!